# Offline HDD keeps spinning under windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, spinup

I have a mini box (laptop based hardware) with windows 10 x64 installed on msata based SSD. Power plan set to *Never Sleep*. I have a SATA 2.5' HDD for backup purpose.

The HDD just keeps spinning even set offline in Partition Management.

I suspect it's hardware related or caused by SSD-HDD mix. Is there a way to prevent the HDD from spinning when idle?

Edit: HDD connected through internal SATA3 port. I've waited day long and HDD spin down won't happen. Haven't tried on other systems yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep harddrive spinning / prevent spindown?](http://superuser.com/questions/854349/how-to-keep-harddrive-spinning-prevent-spindown).  While the author of the duplicate question is using Windows 8.1 the answer to the question still applies to Windows 10.

Comment: That question asks how to prevent spindown, while this question seeks solutions to activate spindown. The answer to one won't *necessarily* (unless you're quite computer literate and willing to muck around) help with the other.

Answer (score 0):

For many years I've been using utility **[RevoSleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/)** for exactly that purpose - it has simple taskbar popup menu that allows to manually or automatically spin-down (sleep) or spin-up (wake) any hard drive of your computer.

While this tool is originally made almost 8 years ago for Windows XP, it still works even these days in Windows 10. I suggest to check that out.